How to color a particle system with shader nodes
In my setup I color the particles by their Z value as shown in the image. Is it possible to color them based on whether they are inside or outside a reference sphere, as in the second image, or on the front or back side of a reference plane? Do I need to create the particles themselves with a geometry node?

if animation nodes (free add-on) as solution ok for you?

I didn't know about animation nodes, but it looks very useful. Thank you.

it has a particle info node, which which you get all locations of all particles. Then you need just simple math to check whether the particle is in a sphere or not
